# Selecting rows from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I appreciate there are many tutorials and examples out there explaining JOIN concepts- however I am struggling to apply the examples to my specific scenario. I would appreciate some help, and if it isn't too much to ask- a break down of what is going on in the solution to achieve the desired results.

3 Tables: users, assessments, assessment_log.

users

```
+--------+------+------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+------+----------+
| UserID | User | Pass | FirstName | LastName | LastLogin | Email | Mobile | Kenitalla | AccountStatus | Role | Operator |
+--------+------+------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+------+----------+
```

assessments

```
+--------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+----------+
| AssessmentID | Name | Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 | RoleRequired | Required | Renewal | Operator |
+--------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

assessment_logs

```
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------+---------+
| AssessmentLogID | Date | AssessmentName | AssessedBy | UserID | StaffName | Comments | Verdict1 | Verdict2 | Verdict3 | Verdict4 | Verdict5 | Verdict | RenewalPeriod | NextDue |
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

When a user takes an assessment, an entry goes in to the assessment_log. Some assessments are required (true or false in Required column) where as some are optional. The RoleRequired column stipulates which user Role the assessment is required for.

I would like to generate a list of users and assessments they are yet to pass. The assessments must be required, and the required role must match the users role. An absense of an entry into the assessment_log with a "Pass" in the Verdict column indicates the assessment has not yet been passed.

In plain speak, I am looking for a query that will achieve the following result:

```
+------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| assessments.Name | users.FirstName | users.LastName |
+------------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Where the assessment is required (Required equals true), the RequiredRole matches the users.Role column, and there is no entry in the assessments_log for the assessment where the Verdict column holds a "Pass" value.

Please let me know if further clarification is required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a LEFT JOIN.

First, we generate a cross product of assessments and users, which contains for each user, all assessments that are required for their role.

Then, a LEFT JOIN checks if these assessments were passed.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    users u
    JOIN assessments a ON (a.RoleRequired = u.Role)
    LEFT JOIN assessment_logs al ON (
            al.AssessmentID = a.AssessmentID
        AND al.UserID = u.UserID
        AND al.Verdict='Pass'
    )

WHERE 
        a.required
    AND al.UserID IS NULL
```

Comment: This seems to give me the result I expect- thank you for that! I will look into LEFT JOINs in more detail... even with your clear example and explanation, I am struggling with the concept.

It seems as though you have chained additional criteria onto the LEFT JOIN- the examples I read refer to selecting rows from one table and returning rows from the second table (the right) where rows match.

Can you explain the "AND al.UserID = u.UserID" and "AND al.Verdict = 'Pass'" portion of the query?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx It works the same as a normal (inner) join, except when no row matching the conditions in the JOIN ON() is found, a dummy, all-NULL row is returned instead. Thus, a LEFT JOIN b ON (cond) WHERE b.id IS NULL will return the rows in a where no row in b matches (cond). Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute names are inconsistent between tables and, although I don't see any duplicate names, it's probably only a matter of time before you do, so I suggest you fix this.

In the meantime, here's how to rename the columns on the fly in order to simplify the join syntax:

```
SELECT AssessmentName, UserLastName, UserFirstName
  FROM ( SELECT FirstName AS UserFirstName, Lastname AS UserLastName, Role
           FROM users ) u
       NATURAL JOIN
       { SELECT Name AS AssessmentName, RoleRequired AS Role
           FROM assessments
          WHERE Required ) a
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT AssessmentName
           FROM assessment_logs
          WHERE Verdict = 'Pass' ) l;
```